# proof that if $|z|< \frac {1}{2}$ so $|ln(1+z)| \le 2|z|$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to proof that if $|z|<\frac {1}{2}$ for $z \in \Bbb C$  so:

$|ln(1+z)|=|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {(-1)^{n+1}}{n}z^n|\le2|z|$

I proved that $R=1$ is the convergance radius.

iv`e tried to do some inequalities: $|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {(-1)^{n+1}}{n}z^n| \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\frac {(-1)^{n+1}}{n}z^n|<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|z|^n<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\frac {1}{2}|^n=2$

for my proof I need to proof that $|ln(1+z)|< 1$ and it will be enough.
but I don`t have any idea from where I bring $\frac {1}{2}$ to multiply my last constant in the inequalities chain.

Comment: What happens if you convert $n-1$ of the $|z|$'s to $\frac{1}{2}$ (and factor out the remaining one)?

Comment: Your last equality is false.  This geometric series does not sum to $2$, but $1$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr you are right! I`m a dumb one HaHaHa..

Comment: Why would $|\ln(1+z)|<1$ be enough? Since $|z|<\frac12$, we'll have $2|z|<1$. In particular, $2|z|$ is a better bound than just $1$.

Comment: @Clayton you right, I don`t have any idea how to proof that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track. We have $|\log(1+z)|$ bounded above by

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{|z|^n}{n} = |z|\left(1 +\frac{|z|}{2} + \frac{|z|^2}{3} + \frac{|z|^3}{4}+\cdots\right) \le |z|\left(1 +\frac{|z|}{2} + \frac{|z|^2}{2} + \frac{|z|^3}{2}+\cdots\right) \le |z|\left(1 +\frac{1/2}{2} + \frac{1/2^2}{2} + \frac{1/2^3}{2}+\cdots\right) = |z|\frac{3}{2}.$$